# angular.element.scope() returns undefined after upgrading latest verion angular-ui-bootstrap 1.3.1

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am upgrading my angularjs, I have upgrade angular-ui-bootstrap 1.3.1 from 0.12.0 with the angularjs version is 1.4.5.

now there is a breakable change I found in my application that angular.element.scope() returns undefined. below is how I try to fetch the scope which was working with older versions

```
 angular.element('#myController').scope()
```

below is the html code

```
<div id="myController" ng-controller="userPermissionsController">
```

the only difference I found in older and newer version is that angular.element('#myController') returns the element with the added css class "ng-scope" which is not added when working with newer version

anybody any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with angular-ui-bootstrap, Angular no longer exposes the scope() method on the angular element by default.  See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) under the jQuery/jqLite extras section where it talks about the scope method.  Angular removed that feature to improve performance, so I would caution against continuing to use that approach.